# How to add a title to a quilt.plot and a title to it manual scale?

Tags: r, legend-properties

I've generated a `quilt.plot` from my data, where the x is Horizontal distance downwind of source (m), y is lateral distance (m) and z is the number of particles.

I'm trying to add a title to phis plot and a title to the legend but I'm not able to do it, I tried the following but not working.
  [corresponding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n26aS.png)

```r
quilt.plot(x=depositionStats_y$xbins, y=depositionStats_y$ybins, z=depositionStats_y$n,
           nx=100,ny=100,xlim=c(-10,100),ylim=c(-80,80),FUN = function(x) sum(x),
           xlab="Horizontal distance downwind of source (m)",ylab="lateral distance (m),
           "title = "Deposited/remaining pestecides mass fraction")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,color = "black", size = 12, face = "italic"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `fields` to install, but reading [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fields/versions/10.3/topics/image.plot), suggests this might work.

```
quilt.plot(x=depositionStats_y$xbins, y=depositionStats_y$ybins, z=depositionStats_y$n,
           nx=100,ny=100,xlim=c(-10,100),ylim=c(-80,80),FUN = function(x) sum(x),
           xlab="Horizontal distance downwind of source (m)",
           ylab="lateral distance (m)",
           legend.lab = "Deposited/remaining pestecides mass fraction")
```

Comment: Thx it's working. Still that i have to arrange the position of the legend 'cause it puts it in the right side of the plot

Answer (score 0):

In addition to proposed solution (adding a title to the legend), this option allows to add a title to the quilt.plot

```
quilt.plot(x=depositionStats_y$xbins, y=depositionStats_y$ybins, z=depositionStats_y$n,
           nx=100,ny=100,xlim=c(-10,100),ylim=c(-80,80),FUN = function(x) sum(x),
           xlab="Horizontal distance downwind of source (m)",
           ylab="lateral distance (m)",
           main = "Deposited/remaining pestecides mass fraction")
```